# Loop back address

Tags: ip-address, ping, loopback-address

When i ping 127.0.0.1 and any address of 127 series(except 127.0.0.0 and 127.255.255.255),i am not finding any difference.Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: have a look at some useful answers here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/157496/why-is-loopback-ip-address-from-127-0-0-1-to-127-255-255-254

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback.  "any address in the range 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254 is mapped to [the loopback network]".

Comment: Then, why only 127.0.0.1 is referred to as localhost,but not others?
Sorry for the noob question.. but just wanted to clarify

Comment: By convention, localhost is usually mapped to 127.0.0.1.  See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3330.txt

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is the 127.x.x.x network. regardless only you can ping it from your machine. Other machines will have to ping you machines address that either you have designated or retrieved from the DHCP server.